# Relational schema and integrity constraints

Tags: postgresql

May I ask if these integrity constraints can be created over this schema using create script?

1. club (klub) can have exactly one coach (trener)
2. club can have just one owner (majitel)
3. each member (člen) can be in just one club
4. and a coach can set tactics (taktika) only for his club?

Is it possible to solve this with integrity constraints in the create script at all or are triggers used for it? I am a part of my create script.

**Schema**

[image]

**Create script**

```
CREATE TABLE club (
id_club SERIAL NOT NULL,
nazev VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
datum_zalozeni VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE club ADD CONSTRAINT pk_club PRIMARY KEY (id_club);
ALTER TABLE club ADD CONSTRAINT uc_club_nazev UNIQUE (nazev);

CREATE TABLE coach (
    id_member INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE coach ADD CONSTRAINT pk_coach PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

CREATE TABLE member (
    id_member SERIAL NOT NULL,
    id_club INTEGER NOT NULL,
    jmeno VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    prijmeni VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    narodnost VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    datum_narozeni VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT pk_member PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

CREATE TABLE owner (
    id_member INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE owner ADD CONSTRAINT pk_owner PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

CREATE TABLE player (
    id_member INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cislo VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    post VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE player ADD CONSTRAINT pk_player PRIMARY KEY (id_member);

ALTER TABLE coach ADD CONSTRAINT fk_coach_member FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES member (id_member) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE member ADD CONSTRAINT fk_member_club FOREIGN KEY (id_club) REFERENCES club (id_club) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE owner ADD CONSTRAINT fk_owner_member FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES member (id_member) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE player ADD CONSTRAINT fk_player_member FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES member (id_member) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```